# get fileupload id in code behind when the page inside masterpage

Tags: asp.net

i want to know how can i access fileupload control id when the whole content is inside contentplaceholder1.i have tried using FindControlRecursive(Control Root, string Id) method and i have called it like FindControlRecursive(contentplaceholder1, fileupload1) but its not working.so plz give some idea how can i find the fileupload1 id

Comment: where is your fileupload control added?

Comment: i have a fileupload control with id fileuplaod1 when i define it like Fileupload fileupload1 in codebehind file it without masterpage it works fine,but adding the page to masterpage creats problems it doesnt find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MasterPage` control's `FindControl` method to find the `FileUpload` control within the `Content` page.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ContentPlaceHolder content = Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;    
    FileUpload fu = content.FindControl("FileUpload1") as FileUpload;
    //...
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error on Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");    
cant convert implicitly from system.web.ui.control to system.web.ui.control.contentplaceholder

Comment: You need to cast to a ContentPlaceHolder, i have edited the example.